# Array só mostra uma linha

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho o seguinte Código, só que ele aparece apenas a primeira linha quando clico em enviar, e quero que apareça todas conforme eu for adicionando mais produtos.

OBS: PARA ADICIONAIS MAIS PRODUTO, ELE FUNCIONA. 
NÃO CONSIGO USAR O FOR PARA PEGAR TODOS OS DADOS.

Obrigada

Segue o Código.

```
<!--CODIGO PHP PARA QUE PEGA OS DADOS-->

  for( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA']); $i++ )
{
    echo 'Nome produto: '.$_POST['NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA'][$i].'--';
    echo 'Quantidade Produto: '.$_POST['QUANTIDADE_PRODUTO'][$i].'--';
    echo 'valor produto: '.$_POST['VALOR_PRODUTO'][$i].'--';

}
```

```js
<!--CODIGO JS PARA adicionais mais linhas-->

$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
  $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
  $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
     if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     }
  });
  }
 
  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
  novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
  novoCampo.find("input").val("");
  novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
  removeCampo();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
  
 
  <tr><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Qtde</td><td class="bd_titulo">Produto</td><td class="bd_titulo">Valor R$</td></tr>
  <tr class="linhas">
    <td>
      <select style="width: 80px;" name="QUANTIDADE_PRODUTO[]" >
                <option value="1" selected >1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                
              </select>


    </td>
    <td>
       <select name="NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA[]" class="textfield_single_outro" id="NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA"  >
                                                          <option value="" selected>Selecione o Produto</option>
                                                          <option value="Produto1" selected>Produto1</option>
                                                          <option value="Produto2" selected>Produto2</option>
                                                          
                              
              </select>
    </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="VALOR_PRODUTO[]" style="text-align:center"  /></td>
   
    <td><a href="#" id="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-menos_318-59392.jpg" border="0" style="width: 7%;"/></a></td>
    <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" id="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-mais_318-40643.jpg" border="0" style="width: 3%;" /></a>
  </td></tr>

  </tr>
     
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/adicionar-linhas2.php)

No seu html vc usa id para as linhas

`<a href="#" id="removerCampo"` .......  E   `<a href="#" id="adicionarCampo"`

só que no script as linhas

`$(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
 $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {`

e

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
```

fazem referencia as classes `.removerCampo` e  `.adicionarCampo`

**Script**

```
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<div id="tudo">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">

  <tr><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Qtde</td>
  <td class="bd_titulo">Produto</td>
  <td class="bd_titulo">Valor R$</td></tr>

  <tr class="linhas">
    <td>
        <select style="width: 80px;" name="QUANTIDADE_PRODUTO[]" >
                <option value="1" selected >1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>            
    </td>
    <td>
       <select name="NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA[]" class="textfield_single_outro" id="NOME_PRODUTO_COMPRA"  >
         <option value="" selected>
            Selecione o Produto</option>
         <option value="Produto1">
            Produto1</option>
         <option value="Produto2">
            Produto2</option>                        
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="valor[]" style="text-align:center" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-menos_318-59392.jpg" border="0" style="width: 7%;"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-mais_318-40643.jpg" border="0" style="width: 3%;" /></a>
    </td></tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="btn-cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" /></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

> foi corrigido também um erro na estrutura da tabela, o ultimo  `<tr>` fora do lugar e também no segundo select que todos os options estavam como selected

### Mas também pode usar id

**Script**

```
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $("#removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $("#removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    ..........
<a href="#" id="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-menos_318-59392.jpg" border="0" style="width: 7%;"/></a>
..........
<a href="#" id="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/sinal-de-mais_318-40643.jpg" border="0" style="width: 3%;" /></a>
.........
```

Comment: Sensacional, Obrigada.